# tinymce - fontsizeselect formats display value

Tags: javascript, fonts, tinymce, size

I'm trying to change the display values of the select box used to pick the right font size of a text. We use TinyMCE 4 editor and this configuration:

```
fontsize_formats: "0.6667rem 0.8333rem 1rem 1.167rem 1.333rem 1.5rem",
```

But the problem is that we want to show the sizes in pixels instead of rem.

In font_formats it's quite simple `font_formats: 'Arial=arial` but unfortunately that does not work in our case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something very similar with `fontsize_formats` in your configuration object:

```
fontsize_formats: "small=12pt medium=1.2em large=24px xlarge=10pt"
```

The first value is what you see in the select list and the second is what is actually applied in the HTML.

If I apply large and medium to portions of a paragraph I end up with this:

```
<p>
    This is 
    <span style="font-size: 24px;"><strong>default</strong></span> 
    content loaded into 
    <span style="font-size: 1.2em;">TinyMCE</span>
</p>
```